# Android - how to read first line of the string

Tags: android

i have string with \n, i would like to read first line of the string. i have tried following but its giving error.

```
                String lines[] = plain.split("\\r?\\n");
                String a = String.parse(lines[0]);
                String b = String.parse(lines[1]);
```

in same time if someone tells me how to replace first line data with another value would be great.

my data is as follows

123456

A B C D

p o s j s u w

Thanks

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: `my data is as follows`. Do not specify it like that. Better: Show in code how you put that in `String plain`.

Comment: thats what i got in string ...

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean to only put `\n` and `\r` using double back slash will give you a literal `\n`

```
"\\n" = \n
"\n" = newline
```

I'm also not sure about your `?` in the line

I think you want something like this (depending on the type of line endings):

```
String[] lines = plain.Split(new string[] {"\r\n", "\n", "\r" },StringSplitOptions.None);
```

After that you should probably step through your string array using for each or similar, not just assume that a you will have a `[0]` and `[1]` in the array.

However assuming you do have two lines accessing them will be

```
a = lines[0];
b = lines[1];
```

replacing a value would be

```
a = lines[0].replace("stuff","things");
```

Comment: `?` is a regex spl. character that marks `\r` optional. Both \ and \\ would work in the expression. \ makes it a literal and \\ makes it work as the same control character in regex.

Comment: @ken-sands i have string plain with some raw data but i break them into many lines, now how i can to read first line of string...

Comment: Ahh so that would be if it was a Regex.Split() That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Hope fully this will help yours..

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "123456\n"
                + "\n"
                + "A B C D\n"
                + "\n"
                + "p o s j s u w\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Thanks";
        String[] lines = data.split("\\n");
          System.out.println("Before "+Arrays.toString(lines));
        lines[0]=lines[0].replace("123456","ABCD PUUJA");
        System.out.println("After "+Arrays.toString(lines));
    }

}
```

Comment: `+ "Thanks";` :-). `data.split("\\n");`. That should be `data.split("\n");`.

Answer (score 1):

To read a line we use:

```
 String myline = reader.readLine()
```

Now in your case we can use the follwoing code to read the first line however We will not use "\n" but we will look for another character like "&", "$" or even "#" and use it as below:

```
String mytext = "This is my code.$ I want to read the first line here.$ Please check it out";  
thetext = mytext .replace("$", System.getProperty("line.separator"));

String[] strings = TextUtils.split(mytext, "$");
String a = strings[0].trim();
String b = strings[1].trim();
```

String a is the first line while String b is the second line

Answer (score 0):

In case you use Kotlin, you can use [lines() method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/lines.html)

```
val myString = "Hello \n NewLine"
myString.lines() // this will give you a List<String> type
```